build_runner is not working ( niether for hive nor for isar) , i am using hive currently
import 'package:moneylog/logsheet_model.dart';
import 'package:moneylog/logpage.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

part 'log_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Log extends HiveObject{

  @HiveField(0)
  double amount ;

  @HiveField(1)
  String category ;

  @HiveField(2)
  String description  ;

  Log({required this.amount ,required this.category, this.description = ""});
}

//this class uses log class , both are present in same file
class LogBook extends ChangeNotifier {}

targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      hive_generator:hive_generator:
        generate_for:
          - lib/*.dart
        options:
          output_extensions: ['.g.dart', '.hive_generator.g.part']
//my build.yaml file

name: moneylog
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none'



version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.1 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_slidable: ^3.1.0
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  provider: ^6.1.2
  slidable_widget: ^0.0.1
  hive:
  hive_flutter:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator:
  build_runner: ^2.4.11  

//My pubspec.yaml

After my build_runner ran and it generated no files ,
I tried - flutter clean and flutter pub get
I tried - dart run build_runner doctor , which led me to create a build.yaml file
I was displayed the following warning : Builder hive_generator:hive_generator outputs .hive_generator.g.part  from .dart which is not specified in the build.yaml
I tried - dart run build_runner clean and dart run build_runner build
I also tried - dart run build_runner --delete-conflicting-outputs
Request : I am new to StackOverflow & Flutter development , bcz of which it is possible that my code may contain formatting error.
I sincerely request you to please tell me about my error so that i can edit it and not close the problem.
I will be really thankful

Where is the file log_model.dart located, in the folder lib?

Yes it is located in lib folder

You only need a build.yaml file if you want to enable/disable or configure builders. It should also work without this file, using the default settings. I would recommend cloning and building a sample (hive or isar) project for example https://github.com/isar/isar/tree/main/examples/pub
